# c program shell input through php

Tags: php, c, shell

I am trying to develop something that could execute c programs through php, using `system()` , `exec()` commands, and it does execute the c program, but the problem here is - If a c program contains `scanf()` statement, the `system()` doesn't ask for user input on a php webpage.

I'm pretty not sure that it can be done.

```
<?php

$content = $_POST['content']; //Getting the code from web form
$file = fopen("code.cpp","w"); //Opening a file in write mode
fwrite($file,$content); //Store the code to file code.cpp



$my_file = 'code.cpp';

system("gcc {$my_file} 2> error.txt"); //Compile a c program and log the errors to error.txt

$error = file_get_contents("error.txt"); //Getting contents of error.txt to a variable

if($error=='')
    system("./a.out"); //Executing the c program
else{
$fp = fopen("error.txt","r");    
while (! feof($fp)){             //Printing the output line by line
echo fgets($fp). "<br />";
}
}
fclose($content);

unlink('a.out');
unlink('code.cpp');

?>
```

I've hosted the php page on a `gcc` installed ubuntu machine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This looks evil, every one with access to that php script can inject and ececute arbitrary code

Comment: Do you have any solution for it? I want to execute a c program that should take in user inputs on php webpage and execute it on the same page, is that even possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the security issues...

1. Create an input file form the data from `$_POST`.
2. Redirect the content of the file while executing the progrm.

Here's the updated PHP file.

```
<?php

$content = $_POST['content']; //Getting the code from web form
$file = fopen("code.cpp","w"); //Opening a file in write mode
fwrite($file,$content); //Store the code to file code.cpp
fclose($file);

$inputData = $_POST['inputData']; //Getting the data from web form
$file = fopen("input.txt","w"); //Opening a file in write mode
fwrite($file,$inputData); //Store the data to file input.txt
fclose($file);

$my_file = 'code.cpp';

system("gcc {$my_file} 2> error.txt");

$error = file_get_contents("error.txt");

if($error=='')
   system("./a.out < input.txt");
else {
   $fp = fopen("error.txt","r");    
   while (! feof($fp)){
      echo fgets($fp). "<br />";
   }
}

unlink('a.out');
unlink('input.txt');
unlink('code.cpp');

?>
```